# Someone stole my answer and Insulted me

Tags: discussion

Someone stole my answer on a post, and pasted it as their answer. And then insulted me in comments that I copied, whereas revisions on stackoverflow clearly mention who posted first. I was made to look like I cheated when I did not, and the person who asked accepted the other person's answer. I do not care about 15 points for an accepted answer, but I do care about getting some respect when helping people in your community. Even if little.

Should I quit using stackoverflow? Is there no moderator attention for quality? I do not want to post the link of that post because I do not want to disrespect anyone. Moderators can find that post easily.

Here is the link as per Oded's request

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098807/ajax-not-returning-mysql-data-in-select/

Comment: You will need to provide links if you want us to see what you are talking about and discuss it in any meaningful way.

Comment: Please post the link. If you aren't prepared to stand by your accusation, then don't make it.

Comment: I just pasted it

Comment: Well, I don't see any _copying_ of answers (if anything, code was copied from the _question_), though I agree that the comments by the other user are not appropriate.

Comment: However, you did say that you, by choice, would leave SO. Why say something silly like that?

Comment: Because i felt that if SO's sytem clearly shows i did not copy any answer and still i can be made to look like i did then i really don't belong here. If anyone can simply remove their answer and use my answer in an edit and then make me look like the one who copied then yes, as insignificant it would be for SO, i would realy like to leave

Comment: well, @HankyPanky see the comments and compare the time difference! and Codesen was also there when we were talking about the solution

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd see my comment underneath OP quetion's comments!

Comment: well, see that comment, see that comment, see that comment, see that comment, see that comment

Comment: @Heart you don't have any comment on Stack Overflow since Dec 3rd, got not idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Why are we arguing over answers to a question closed as too localized? The question will likely be deleted and all the reputation from it vanish. Why didn't you just let it go?

Comment: well, @HankyPanky i am sorry if it disrespect you! I am really sorry bro! But I want to say buddy i swear i didn't copy your answer! Well, that was a co-incidence bro that we both have same answer! You think that earned 1k respect by copying other questions? I am a fool guy who can't do anything? :'( well, if i said you something or which disrespected you i am sorry for that! Before this question i answered a question in which mbnittie stoled my answer and post it as its own! I know it really feels bad when you think that your idea  is copied by other but I swear i not copied your answer :'(

Comment: This account is mine. Heart is Aspiring Aqib and Aspiring Aqib in Real has name Muhammad Talha Akbar!

Comment: well, @ShaWizDowArd I want a person for my site. Not gonna pay him for that. But Work as Team Member. I am making a social website and i need CSS designer. Well, In which section of stackoverflow i post this? METASTACKOVERFLOW?

Comment: now its getting suspicious  ...

Comment: @Heart no idea what you're blubbering about. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1726699/heart) is **your** account on Stack Overflow. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1887854/aspiring-aqib) is the account of the user in discussion here. Not same account and if you are the same person then just be careful to not cross vote or you'll get suspended. Have the best of luck.

Comment: Here's another post where he does that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090145/mysql-get-total-number-of-orders-and-sum-of-total-by-user/14090188#14090188

Someone should probably investigate...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should have flagged his comments as offensive, and flaged his post for mod attention with the custom message "copied from `<link>`". Though *now* you don't have to, you've written this post which will notify the mods anyway.

> Is there no moderator attention for quality?

Unfortunately, we have too many posts on SO for mods to comb through individually. Which is why flagging is the way to go in such cases -they'll never find it if it isn't flagged.

Comment: Thank You @Manishearth. That's so true. And thanks to everyone who gave their input, now i am 100% sure that this does matter to SO. Quality is prefered here.

Comment: Of course it is. I'm not sure how you got the idea that "there is no moderator attention for quality" - surely you didn't expect the moderators to step in at the very moment the other user posted his answer, did you?