# I answered a question and now a person is disturbing me

Tags: support

I posted an answer on Stack Overflow, and now a person is [disturbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108359/html5-digial-clock-animation/14108414#comment19522122_14108414) me. They say that I should have posted that answer as a comment. The questioner said thanks for my answer! He said that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108414/23897) works. How should I deal with this?

Comment: First, as also asked on [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160942/someone-stole-my-answer-and-insulted-me), why do you have two accounts, Heart and Aspiring Aqib?

Comment: That is: why not just post on meta with the Aspiring Aqib account, as it would be less confusing?

Comment: @DavidRobinson well, when i had issue in previous question! one of the member of meta told me that HUNKY PUNKY has posted something ! I logged in meta.stackoverflow.com using facebook and the account in which i was logged in was an other account so, stackoverflow made an account of HEART instead of Aspiring Aqib

Comment: What is going on.

Comment: @Heart - I think you can merge the two accounts if you wanted. It would actually give you the 100 reputation account association, as well as make it less confusing. ;)

Comment: To be clear- was Heart a different *person's* account, or a different account that *you* used?

Comment: Related: [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments)

Comment: I still don't understand why you keep opening new accounts for Meta instead of simply using the same account. You will get +100 rep bonus on both sites, you know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at the answer you posted, it's a wall of code with a link to a JSFiddle. This is by no means something that should have been a comment -- it is an answer -- but there are some things that you can do to improve your answer and make it really awesome.

First, good job putting the working demo in a JSFiddle, and for clearly marking where the problem was in the code. However, for clarity, I'd suggest also writing a sentence or two at the top describing what you put in the comment:

> ...you typed setIntervalTimer instead of setInterval.

Upon first look, it appears as if the entire block of code is the answer, when it's really just one line. So make it absolutely 100% clear what the answer is, and use the wall of code as the working example.

With that out of the way, you're on the Internet, and you're going to have people say things to you. While you can't control everyone else's behavior, you can control your own, and by replying the way you did, you escalated the comment thread into a fight. My suggestion is to think about what the person is saying to you and ask yourself if there isn't more you can do to make the answer better. In this case, there is.

Second, if you reply, assume the person has the best interests of Stack Overflow in mind. Don't start a fight with them. Keep the conversation constructive, and if it starts to degrade, move on.

Comment: +1 for "*you're on the Internet, and you're going to have people say things to you*"

Comment: well, @jmort253 why they fight? i answered, it helped him and now what's the problem with that guy?

Comment: What the commenter was probably referring to is that David Thomas found the bug in his comment 4 minutes before @AspiringAqib's answer. This isn't the first time this user has been found to crib answers from other users- see [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160942/someone-stole-my-answer-and-insulted-me)

Comment: oh cribbing answer? well @DavidRobinson don't you know there are 10000 people online at stackoverflow and can't there be a co-incidence that guys can have same answer?

Comment: Considering the fact that the problem is so trivial, a syntax error, I'd be hesitant to say that someone -- Heart, in this case -- was acting against the best interests of Stack Overflow. As Shog9 points out, comments shouldn't be used as answers, and it's clear David Thomas didn't intend to post an answer, as he's a 60K rep user who knows that comments aren't answers, and he's taking the easy way out by helping the user without committing to writing an actual answer.

Comment: well, David Thomas only posted console error he didn't pointed out where the problem was! if you say that i copied his comment as answer buddy then finding an error was also a big achievement because all the code lied on that single mistake

Comment: @Heart You're doing it again. To be clear, posting the answer was the correct thing to do. The problem is the confrontational tone with which you were carrying out the conversation.

Comment: @heart aside from ignoring the comments you can also flag the post and put a custom message, or do you want you did which is to put a post on meta. Personally I would just ignore it, unless it's offensive to a lot of people and not just me.

Comment: Hi Heart, David Thomas is who posted the comment in the Stack Overflow answer, not David Robinson. ;)  Wrong guy. :)  With that said, my suggestion is to think about why people might be thinking you're stealing others' answers and try to find a way to avoid them thinking that. If someone posts a comment that could be an answer, I personally tell them they should post it as an answer. If they don't come back in a reasonable time period, then I post it myself and mention their name in my answer. This removes the doubt that I was trying to do anything sneaky. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: well, buddy i wanna clear to all that i haven't earned 1k + respect by copying answers on STACKOVERFLOW! In previous issue that guy HUNKY PUNKY don;t know the exact name but he took a revenge, he opened my all answers and downvoted each one of them but stackoverflow reversed all the downvotes saying that there was serial downvoting!

Comment: @jmort253 but i am being involved in copier list from yesterday! we were finding solution for the answer and i didn;t even looked at his answer and the OP also didn;t looked his answer! i thought to first comment the solution and i did that and then i thought of earning some repo so i edited my answer and wrote solution in it but after some time i saw one notif which was HUNKY PUNKY comment in which he wrote "same as mine" when he commented that still i haven't seen his answer check the question link he posted in issue i posted a image there is proof "An edit is made to this post"

Comment: @Heart "Second, if you reply, assume the person has the best interests of Stack Overflow in mind. Don't start a fight with them. Keep the conversation constructive, and if it starts to degrade, move on." - You know, like when you've been told >5 times this month to indent your code and watch out for SQLI vulnerabilities and you just ignore the comments or worse, insult the one who is trying to help (and keep on doing the same thing in your next answers).

Comment: first time i got 17 notifs and 12 inbox messages due to you @OneMore :P